# creating multi sheet excel file using classic asp

Tags: excel, asp-classic

I am working on a project and I need to create a multi sheet excel file using classic asp.

Here is my code. It makes a multi sheet excel but I cant write anything on sheet 2 or 3:

```
<%
  response.charset = "UTF-8"
  Response.Buffer=true

  Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=aaa.xls"  
  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel" 
%>
<HTML xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
<HEAD>
<xml>
<x:ExcelWorkbook>
<x:ExcelWorksheets>
<x:ExcelWorksheet>
<x:Name>sheet1</x:Name>
<x:WorksheetOptions>
<x:Print>
<x:ValidPrinterInfo>
</x:Print>
</x:WorksheetOptions>
</x:ExcelWorksheet>
<x:ExcelWorksheet>
<x:Name>sheet2</x:Name>
<x:WorksheetOptions>
<x:Print>
<x:ValidPrinterInfo>
</x:Print>
</x:WorksheetOptions>
</x:ExcelWorksheet>
</x:ExcelWorksheets>
</x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<TABLE>
<%
dim  oConn
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rs, ds
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Response.Write "<tr>"
Response.Write "<td style='border-left:none;border:.5pt solid windowtext;' bgcolor='#CCCCCC' bordercolor='#000000'><b>"
Response.Write "aa"
Response.Write "</b></td>"
Response.Write "</tr>"
Response.Write "<tr>"
Response.Write "<td>"
Response.Write "bb"
Response.Write "</td>"
Response.Write "</tr>"
%>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to create actual .xls / .xlsx files in Classic ASP without a third party component (such as EasyXLS.ExcelDocument).

But what you can do is generate your Excel file using XML markup within Classic ASP, export it with a .xls extension and Excel will convert the file when you open it (after a warning message).

For example:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%

    Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=aaa.xls"  
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel" 

%><?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author>Author Name</Author>
  <LastAuthor>Author Name</LastAuthor>
  <Created>2020-05-20T13:19:37Z</Created>
  <LastSaved>2020-05-20T13:21:04Z</LastSaved>
  <Company>Company Name</Company>
  <Version>14.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>4695</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>14355</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>360</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>105</WindowTopY>
  <ActiveSheet>2</ActiveSheet>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1A - Sheet 1</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet2">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1A - Sheet 2</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet3">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1A - Sheet 3</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Selected/>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
     <ActiveRow>6</ActiveRow>
     <ActiveCol>3</ActiveCol>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

The above example has 3 populated sheets. Best thing to do would be to create a dummy template of the type of Excel layout you're looking to generate, populate the sheets with dummy data and export from Excel using the "XML Spreadsheet" format (which is all I did for the above example). Then use Classic ASP to replace the dummy data with actual data.